# Webpack-Dev-Server Build Fails To Load In Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, npm, webpack

I was working in `Firefox Developer Version` & while webpack was recompiling the build, I clicked on the next tab & all of a sudden, everything stopped. Firefox became unresponsive & the tab & the window wouldn't close.

Upon restarting the system, I restarted the `webpack-dev-server`. However, both FF & Chrome refuse to load up the page. The systems starts making a lot of noise (busy processing). Firefox becomes unresponsive.

A few things I have tried:

1 - localhost seems to work. I loaded up another PHP app (not using webpack, node & npm), which worked.

2 - `http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/` does not work.After sometime, chrome gives this:
[image]

3 - CLI reports no errors when I run the `webpack-dev-server` command & reports that the bundle is now valid.

4 - Firefox & Chrome, both donot open the Dev tools while processing...

5 - My system is:
 Ubuntu 16.04, 
 node v6.0.0, 
 npm v3.8.6.

Im confused, what could have caused this issue or where to start.
Is my `node.js` corrupt? Could it be `npm`?

Comment: Is this just regarding your project or is it an issue with webpack in general?If you don't know, try to see if you can get [this](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example) example running, and if you do - there is something wierd in your project.

Comment: @JAM thanks for the suggestion. Yes, it is running fine. If the problem is with my build, could it be the build that currently resides in the 'build' folder?

Comment: Hard to say what could be the issue - but it seems that something is taking up all the resources (i.e. an endless `while` loop). Try chekcing the served response to see what it could be (`view-source:http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server`)

Comment: @JAM Thanks, all I get is the HTML skeleton file output. Dev Tools do open, console reports no errors.